# Streching a convex sphere into a concave (inside) of a sphere

Tags: photography

I am looking for a software solution to strech a picture of the outside of a sphere (convex) into an inside (concave) view of this sphere. I suppose it will not be too complicated, but searching for a software allowing this transformation since weeks now, I have not come up with any conclusive answers.

Does anyone know a clever solution? A photo software, which allows over laying a picture onto the INSIDE of a sphere in a quite accurate way?

As I have not even bought the computer I want to run this (missing) program on, I am totally open concerning the OS – and could pay up to 1000 Euro for software.

Comment: My only task I want to be able to do is turn the outside of a sphere with lots of details (photograph) INWARD. So the perspective is inverted, the center no the closest (to the camera), but furthest away part of the final picture. It is a simpel thing to think off, but obviously not commonly used in picture manipulation. I would be very happy to find a solution. What compter I buy depends on what I need for this task. Thanks for help!